# Getting GC overhead limit exceeded while fetching millions of records using JPA createQuery();

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, query-performance

```
String reportQuery="Select pr from ProductivityReport pr where pr.reportDate=:reportDate";
Query query = entityDao.getEntityManager().createQuery(reportQuery,ProductivityReport.class).setHint("org.hibernate.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Here I am trying to fetch a result on the basis of date where I get

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

As I have went for solution to related sites and the solutions are: To implement ScrollableResults if you wants to fetch millions of records but this method is not defined in Query interface in our product.

To apply pagination, but if I hit ResultList more than once, I'm facing an exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed that is due to session closed.

`query.setHint("eclipselink.read-only", "true");` also not working.

Please suggest me an another solution for fetching millions of rows through JPA as I get stuck to those exceptions which in result gives me an unexpected behaviour while generating report i.e. page gets unresponsive.

Comment: You're trying to retrieve so many rows that your JavaVM instance runs out of RAM. It isn't a garbage-collector (GC) issue, it's a too-much-data to handle at once issue. You must figure out how to fetch those rows one at a time or in batches, not all at once.

Comment: Can fetch  data in batches like monthwise.